# Explanation of java instanceof operator incompatible conditional compilation error

Tags: instanceof

Could somebody explain this.
The java instanceof operator gives a compiler error when there is no possible way for an instance to refer to an object. Fine.

Let me present a bit of example code

```
public class InstanceOfConfusing {

class A {}
class B1 extends A {}
class B2 extends A {}

public static void main(String... args) {

    InstanceOfConfusing ioc = new InstanceOfConfusing();

    A a = ioc.new A();
    B1 b1 = ioc.new B1();
    B2 b2 = ioc.new B2();

    boolean t1 = b1 instanceof A; // compiles, true
    boolean t2 = b1 instanceof B1; // compiles, true

    boolean t3 = b1 instanceof B2; // does not compile

    boolean t4 = a instanceof B1; // compiles, false ***

}
```

}

I understand everything except the last line marked with ***. My question is simple, why does this compile?
If the compile gives the "Incompatible conditional operand types" error on the previous line because there is no way for an object of type B1 to ever refer to an instance of type B2, shouldn't it
also know that there is no way for a B1 to refer to an A?

I can't write a line like this: b1 = new A();
I would get a "Type mismatch" compiler error, and rightfully so. So why doesn't the compiler know there is no way for b1 here to reference an instance of type A? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign with downcasting. After doing so, you can understand usage of `a instanceof B1` and why it needs to be compiled.

`B1 b = (B1) new A();`

Comment: Actually, instanceof keyword is for downcasting after upcasting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because B1 extends A, so you can do:

```
A a = new B1()
```

So with `a instanceof B1`, you can check whether a is an instance of B1 wrapped (for example) in an interface of abstract class A